# Security design, maintain email but not linked to associated data?

Tags: asp.net, security, umbraco

my friend and I were thinking of a Web idea and ran into an issue:

We can't allow the email address to be sitting in a database with its associated data, in the case of a hacker obtaining the database. We'd like to ensure the email address and its associated data can never be linked, but then on the other hand we also need to keep them linked somehow so we can send users email notifications E.T.C

Can anyone think or know of a way around this? (.NET, Umbraco)

Thanks!

Comment: so you need a way to have an email address associated with a user, but also have an email address not associated with a user?

Comment: That's so weird. My friend and I had exactly the same web idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have 2 databases, one with users + data + user id, another with user id + email. Secure them both, if one gets discovered, the other one might not be.

In any case you are asking us to prove falsity. ^^

Comment: Henrik is right, this concept is flawed from the beginning.  Either the data are associated, or not.  Maybe you should revise your question to inquire about methods of securing the association between the two?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to link user data with emails without actually linking user data with emails. However, it would be possible to not have the email address stored and linked in a database if you could live with only having their email address when the user is logged in.

You could require users to log in using their email address and password as many sites do, but you could store a one way hash of the email address (such as sha1(email+password) ) rather than the address itself. When the user logs in successfully, you can store their email address in their session without ever having to get it from the database. You could then send them emails until you destroy their session. This would prevent an attacker from connecting their data to their email without brute forcing the hashes or grabbing the session information from memory or user cookies depending on how you store it.

Unfortunately, this wouldn't allow you to send notification emails.